# Adding shipping methods to Woocommerce Order Page for Admin only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I need to add a few shipping methods to our WooCommerce **Edit Order** page.

This will be for admin-only internal use so customers should not be able to see these options.

Is there a hook or custom code that we could add to populate the shipping method dropdown?

There is no additional functionality needed (no tax, rate, etc.)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How did you get that dropdown in the order page ? I'm trying to have the shipping methods in that page and I cannot find anything about it...

Comment: I used jQuery - it worked but is not ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are more ways to achieve what you are looking for. This would be one solution:

**Shipping methods for user roles**

You can solve this problem with user permissions. Only users of the role "administrator" should have the ability to use the shipping method "usps".

Easy way would be to use a free plugin like:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

In this plugin, you can select your User Role and click "Add capability" and hopefully find your shipping method.

There are also solutions exactly for your issue:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-based-shipping-method/
There are also a lot of plugins which are not for free, but may offer some more comfort and support.

---

The harder way is to write a function and make use of woocommerce and wordpress hooks and filters. This is a little bit complex, but I will give you something to start with.

In wordpress, user roles are a set of capabilities.

You can get the role object in wordpress like this:

```
$administrator_role = get_role( 'administrator' );
```

You can add capabilties and remove them:

```
$administrator_role->add_cap( 'custom_capability' );
$administrator_role->remove_cap( 'custom_capability' );
```

Read something about this here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/

---

And fortunately there is a woocommerce filter to make use of.
**Maybe you should take a look at this first, this might totally solve your issue:**

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/

As you see, the filter you want is the:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'your_function', 30, 2);
```

http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_package_rates/

Here is a tutorial, how to make use of it:

https://trackitweb.com/woocommerce-hide-a-shipping-method-based-on-user-role/

The shipping method in the example is called "local pickup":

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_local_pickup_based_on_user_role', 30, 2);

function hide_local_pickup_based_on_user_role($rates, $package) {
  foreach($rates as $rate_key => $rate){
    if($rate->method_id === 'local_pickup'){
      if(!current_user_can('local_pickup_allowed') || !is_user_logged_in()){
        unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $rates;
```

And this is the part, where you check the role capability (and the login), to unset the shipping method for users without this capability:

```
if(!current_user_can('local_pickup_allowed') || !is_user_logged_in()){ ... }
```

I hope this can help you!